# Highavailability/Global Loadbalancing of clusters

Tags: high-availability, cluster, failovercluster

I know this website 1channel.ch which has like 4 servers in 4 different datacenters across the globe (czech republic, estonia, sweden, germany). What happens is as i am browsing this website the server changes meaning he is balancing the server load in realtime among the datacenters.

How is he doing this? What softwares or applications are needed to achieve this?

Any expert advice as to the best practices in achieving this will be ethernally appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Do a `dig` and it becomes pretty clear:

```
$ dig 1channel.ch

; <<>> DiG 9.7.6-P1 <<>> 1channel.ch
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24955
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1channel.ch.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
1channel.ch.        300 IN  A   50.7.245.186
1channel.ch.        300 IN  A   80.79.118.158
1channel.ch.        300 IN  A   88.80.29.60
1channel.ch.        300 IN  A   88.80.29.63
1channel.ch.        300 IN  A   94.23.54.60
1channel.ch.        300 IN  A   188.40.110.86
```

Multiple A records, and a very low (looks like 5 minutes) TTL. Essentially, [round-robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).

Comment: pretty interesting..never knew there was such a command...so what exactly does that information mean?

Comment: +1. So no "balancing the loa in real time among data Centers". Noone does that - it is stupid, because you arem or e bound by latency most of the time. THis is simple "distribute requests, do not care about load on Servers".